# How to fix sudo command error in terminal

Tags: ubuntu

After few commands:

[image]

I cannot use 'sudo' command or 'ept' command

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

Please post Text instead of images, when possible.

In the second image it tells you that /usr/bin is missing from your path, which is explained by the fact that you've overriden your path variable in the first image.

PATH is an environment variable telling your shell where to look for program files, such as `sudo` and `apt-get`.
This is why you should alsways append values to your path (seperated by ":") instead of overriding it completely.

To fix the problem itself, add /usr/bin back to your path by using
`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"`

Or reload your shell, and then use

`export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`

instead of

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin`

To keep the preset value in addition to the new directory.